# cocotb-modelsim error due to Illegal option -o pipefail

Tags: bash, verilog, modelsim, cocotb

I am trying to run cocotb simulations with modelsim, however, I am getting an error and no success, in the last two days, fixing it.

I have installed cocotb using "pip3 install cocotb". The python version I am using is 3.7.0. I have installed the questa/modelsim Lite version 19.1 (which is free through Intel).

I am able to run cocotb simulations with icarus and verilator, however, with modelsim I run into following error:

```
    mehdi@mehdi:~/Dropbox/Test_Tools/testcocotbVerilator$ make SIM=modelsim
make results.xml
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/mehdi/Dropbox/Test_Tools/testcocotbVerilator'
set -o pipefail; cd sim_build && LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/mehdi/Dropbox/Test_Tools/testcocotbVerilator/build/libs/x86_64::/usr/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/lib MODULE=TB TESTCASE= TOPLEVEL="work.dff" COCOTB_SIM=1 \
GPI_EXTRA= TOPLEVEL_LANG=verilog PYTHONPATH=/home/mehdi/Dropbox/Test_Tools/testcocotbVerilator/build/libs/x86_64:/home/mehdi/Dropbox/Test_Tools/testcocotbVerilator:/home/mehdi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages: \
/home/mehdi/intelFPGA_lite/19.1/modelsim_ase/linuxaloem/vsim -c -64  -do runsim.do 2>&1 | tee sim.log
/bin/sh: 1: set: Illegal option -o pipefail
/home/mehdi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cocotb/share/makefiles/simulators/Makefile.questa:147: recipe for target 'results.xml' failed
make[1]: *** [results.xml] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/mehdi/Dropbox/Test_Tools/testcocotbVerilator'
/home/mehdi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cocotb/share/makefiles/Makefile.sim:79: recipe for target 'sim' failed
make: *** [sim] Error 2
```

I would appreciate it if someone could advise me how should I fix this problem

Comment: Try to use the master branch and follow instructions.

Answer (score 0):

That "-o pipefail" option is only available in bash version 3 or later. So either you're running an older version of bash, or some other non-bash shell that doesn't support it.